# Why is Facebook debugger returning errors?

Tags: facebook

I've created a Facebook App ID for my website. I've entered the code snippet after the opening <body> as instructed by Facebook:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1287268171299753',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.5'
    });
  };
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

My website is running on WordPress. I've used NextGEN FaceBook (NGFB) plugin to generate the Open Graph Metatags. The <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1287268171299753"> was entered manually.

I'm checking a website page, https://mentorgroup.org/2016/01/report-writing-essentials/ on the Facebook debugger.

I'm getting the following errors:

1. Errors That Must Be Fixed. Missing Required Property, The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.
2. Warnings That Should Be Fixed. Inferred Property, The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
3. When shared, this is what will be included. fb:app_id hasn't been included in the meta tags...

Here is a screen shot of the errors:
[image]

I'm wondering why Facebook debugger is giving me errors. I am unable to share any page on Facebook.

Hope somebody can help me here.

Thanks

Comment: When trying to re-scrape your URL, I repeatedly get _“Curl Error : OPERATION_TIMEOUTED Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received”_, and that is likely the root cause of the problem. So see to it that you make your site respond faster. (It takes about 12-13 seconds when I call it in my browser, before your server even _starts_ to send any data.)

Comment: Thanks CBroe, I'm using a theme I created. It's either I use another or check on the queries.

Comment: Hi CBroe, I commented out a query that was not used- Facebook sharing is now working! Thanks again for your assistance